# I think I am micromanaged. What should I do?

Tags: professionalism, manager, people-management, micro-management

I've been in a big company for several years and recently had a new manager coming in. He is pretty senior in terms of working years, but he didn't work in big corporations before and I feel this is causing some problems I recently experienced.

I think the problem is that he is micromanaging. Here is why.

1. He expects me to answer his email / [Teams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Teams) message quickly. None of my former managers has ever told me to be "on call" on Teams on my phone, so he could receive answers from me for any small questions he asks me often, including emails, technical questions, how our system works, etc. This came recently when I didn't reply to his Teams message in about 40 minutes... I'm a bit shocked and speechless to hear the 'on call' words
2. He asked to see the details of my [Outlook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) calendar (who I'm meeting and the details of the meeting)... I politely turned it down as I don't feel comfortable and again have never been asked by my former managers (5+).

I didn’t realize that many would expect it’s the norm for managers to see a report's calendar. It’s not in our industry.

3. I'm pretty experienced in my job and have been quite independent for several years. With my previous managers, I discuss my projects, updates at weekly or biweekly one-on-one. With my new manager, he said I should be more proactive in letting him know what I'm working on... almost on a daily basis. I think it has been putting a bit of a burden on me lately and also affecting my productivity as I have to answer his questions often, chatting with him on many small things in unstructured quick calls, etc.

Am I right that he is micromanaging? What could I do to handle it? Is it time to look for a new job...?

---

Taking in some of the answers so far (appreciate all!), I think what my frustration lies is in that I'd prefer more ownership of my work and not being constantly asked for updates. Also, I think my manager is taking advantage of my time without doing the hard work himself to become familiar with our work, relationships etc. I did spent considerable amount of time in the beginning to help him become familiar with our company and it's more than half a year since he got here.

Maybe it's a bit unfair to assume that he is micromanaging, but there are some components to it for sure. Maybe it's more about his lack of experience and my frustration of our manager-report relationship where I have to constantly teach him things even after his break-in period.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144833/discussion-on-question-by-olala-i-think-i-am-micromanaged-what-should-i-do); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: To be clear with the "on call" thing is this within normal work/office hours or out of hours? Because expecting a reply within 40 minutes when you're in the office seems very reasonable to me, expecting a reply within 40 minutes when you're not at work is borderline insane.

Comment: @Muzer within working hours. we all work remotely

Comment: @Muzer I would say it depends on the medium used. If you want an immediate response, use the phone. If you sent an email to me this implies it is not urgent on a scale of minutes. A response by the next work day is generally sufficient.

Comment: @keshlam like I said earlier, people can see if I’m busy or not by default

Answer (score 67):

> None of my former managers has ever ...

Every manager has a different managing style. It is quite useless to compare managing styles at this level of detail.

> I didn't reply to his Teams message in about 40 minutes

40 min is quite short in astronomical terms. It is very long when an important meeting is coming and some information is needed - but missing.

When my colleagues do not answer me for 40 min when I want to go to lunch (with them), I go to lunch without them before the 40 min expire.

> He asked to see the details of my Outlook calendar

That is 100% his right as a manager.

> I politely turned it down ...

There is nothing polite about that. You were asked to perform a job duty and you refused. Totally unprofessional.

> With my new manager, he said I should be more proactive in letting him know what I'm working on.

Perfectly reasonable. He is new, and he needs to learn about people, about projects, about problems, etc. He cannot learn if people "politely refuse" to provide him information.

> what I'm working on.. almost on a daily basis

I had colleagues who had to work with a new manager when they moved to a new project. That manager asked them to report their activity (by filling in some file) every 15 (fifteen) minutes. That is 4 times every hour. They did it for a short while, to accommodate him, and then they had a discussion with him about finding a better way of cooperating, which would not destroy their productivity.

So reporting once every day or every few days is not such a big deal.

Additionally, I had another experience myself: after I changed jobs, at the new job I was required to CC my technical manager and my business manager in all e-mails that I sent. I complied as long as it was needed for them to begin to trust me. After some time, they requested me to stop CC-ing them, as they already had enough e-mails.

> Am I right that he is micromanaging?

From my point of view, you are the opposite of right. Especially considering the "politely refusing" to cooperate.

> ... independent for several years ...

Being independent is very far from being the Lone Ranger. "Independent" means that you deliver the expected results at the expected quality within the expected time frame without someone reminding you or pushing you. And this applies to project work, as well as non-project work.

BTW: reporting project work is also project work.

---

> I think I am micromanaged, what should I do?

You are most likely not micromanaged. You need to be supportive of the new manager, who needs to learn his way. As an experienced employee, you were expected to be the reliable one. Just imagine your manager's disappointment when he understood that you are one of his trouble guys - after he probably trusted you.

> Is it time to look for a new job...?

That is your choice, we cannot help you there. However, if you will have similar behavior at the new job, please do not be surprised if you will have similar results.

---

**Conclusion**

My best advice: please learn to be more professional and more supportive of your colleagues and your managers. If you do not understand *why* something is required from you, just ask, and you will probably receive an answer. In the situation you described, you practically judged, sentenced and executed your manager before you even considered giving him a chance to learn about his new job and his new colleagues.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i have to admit it's quite refreshing to see your comments. I want to quickly comment on the calendar thing, i've asked a few colleagues on this and in our industry, it's not common for managers to see direct reports' calendar details. It's his right but I don't think it's my job duty.

Comment: well, I didn't describe the whole story so how could you know I didn't give my manager a chance to learn about his new job and his new colleagues, right?

Comment: Regardless of your job, it is your duty to cooperate with your manager, especially when he requests. The only job where your manager should not know some details about your job is a job with the secret services, but then... you would not ask about it here :)

Comment: *"I didn't describe the whole story"* - not even needed. You provided a lot of information for me to have a good overview. If you read my answer again, you will understand better how many key pieces of information you provided. Even if everything else was perfect, what you explained is already enough. Even if he was wrong, you were more wrong than him.

Comment: yeah, I cooperate with my managers and stakeholders but there are things we always discuss/negotiate.. I think many of my friends I know don't 100% do what we were initially asked.

Comment: This answer is spot on. The OP is not being micromanaged by any stretch of the imagination, they are simply in the 'break-in' stage of the professional relationship continuum - both parties are figuring out what works/doesn't work for them, and negotiating the sticking points. Every time I've had a 'new' manager I've had to go through this phase/process to some degree, sometimes with some large bumps while I learned how to manage my new manager ... and I've got four decades of work in my field under my belt with a very long list of accomplishments & happy customers to show for it.

Comment: @Sharpenologist, how long would you typically describe the break in period?

Comment: @olala ... I usually give a new manager about 6 months to settle in, especially if there is clear progress toward what I consider to be the desired relationship. If the manager is new to the company, not just new to managing me/this team, then this timeframe may be longer - they're getting used to a new boss too, so there are almost certainly adjustments that they are having to make to their working style to keep their new boss happy in addition to learning how to work with a new set of peers, and a new customer base - all in addition to developing good working relationships with their staff.

Comment: @Sharpenologist sure, 6 months is long enough. in my specific case, it's been longer than that..

Comment: @olala ... Longer than 6 months + no progress = time to work on (re)setting the boundaries/expectations of the relationship. Start gently ... and perhaps begin by telling them about your working style - prefer not to be interrupted multiple times [be careful with this one! It's still their prerogative to interrupt, because ... well, they're the boss], used to reporting progress/customer issues (scope creep, etc)/blockers in the critical path on a weekly or bi-weekly basis, but don't dump all of these things at once - start with something small and see how they respond. Good luck!

Comment: @sharpenologist exactly what I was thinking on resetting boundaries

Comment: Minor detail: the Range is _Lone_, not _Lonely_.

Comment: @virolino Exactly my read as well. Sounds like OP is more than a little resentful about having to adapt to the (perfectly reasonable, in my view) methods of the new manager. The OP still has options - at a minimum, compliance, as a middle-of-the-road approach, a frank and respectful discussion of roles and responsibilities, and, as an extreme, finding another job.

Comment: "You were asked to perform a job duty" what now?

Comment: Just copy every one of their points and say "No. No. No. Rejected. No". What a low quality answer. You don't respond to OP's concerns you just dismiss them. OP now can't do any work which takes longer concentration than 30 minutes in case there's chat messages to reply to - isn't that worth some genuine response to it more than "100% THEIR RIGHT, TOUGH"?

Comment: Poor answer. It does not respect the OP's existing work patterns or industry practice, and gives enormous deference to an anonymous manager who -- so far -- has not successfully built relationships or delivered value. I see potential red flags such as "expecting me to be "on call" on Teams on my phone". __Competent managers lead by consent, and need to build relationships to do so.__  Other answers address how to enable & improve the relationship in a mutually respectful way. This answer is one-sided and not very helpful.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: If OP asks if X is the case (literally: _"Am I right that he is micromanaging?"_); "No" is a perfectly on-topic answer; and just like how OP was given the platform to add their observations/claims to support their question, the answerer is given the ability to respond to those observations/claims. As to the one concrete thing you respond to, this answer makes it very clear that a reasonable time to respond to a request is contextual, a point you seem to have sorely missed in your response to it.

Comment: @ThomasW: "This manager has not built relationships here and therefore I will refuse to meet any of their requests that would help them find their footing" is putting the cart before the horse, and worse still it _perpetuates_ the unhealthy working relationship. Furthermore, there is no way for you to possibly judge with any measure of accuracy in which context the manager expected a <40min reply. Cherrypicking the example of an IT support role, that is an age to be AWOL (if you're on the clock at that point in time). Do I know they're in IT support? Of course not. But you don't know either.

Comment: @ThomasW: *"Competent managers lead by consent, and need to build relationships to do so."* - that is exactly the point that you completely missed - that OP ONLY consents to be the de-facto manager. Which is totally unacceptable.

Comment: @Flater The OP states he has already "spent considerable amount of time in the beginning to help him become familiar with our company".  He mentions twice his effort to onboard the manager; plus usual weekly updates. I'm reading the negative by implication, but I'm not hearing about the manager's efforts to build the relationship. Hopefully OP will now realize that sharing the calendar is beneficial; but I feel manager may struggle more widely if he relies on command-and-control which is an outdated approach & seems not aligned with established culture in this company.

Comment: @ThomasW: There is usually a significant difference between how long it takes a regular employee and a manager, when both are new to the business, to get familiar with their job. We have no concrete idea on what OP considers to have been sufficient time. Even if weekly update were appropriate in this setting, daily updates can be warranted for an onboarding manager to better understand the processes. It in unclear whether the manager is controlling through command, or if OP is being very selective about _which_ compromises they are willing to make to help the manager onboard.

Comment: @ThomasW, appreciate your comment, you understood what I was trying to say. I think this answer bluntly assumed too many things.

Answer (score 27):

How visible is your work?

The common themes I'm picking up here is that your manager seems to be in the dark about what you're doing.  Their only real approach on how to "fix" this for them is to just...ask you, but this "asking" comes across to you more as "micromanaging".

I'll give them the benefit of the doubt in this case and say that they may not have a convenient or accessible way to know what it is you're working on.

So, what I'd do is the following:

- Put your work into a board, like GitHub or Jira or Asana, and give your boss access to that.  This will allow them to see what you're working on at a glance.
- Look to open up your calendar so that your boss could see what meetings you have on deck. This is something I do in my organization and I don't find it that intrusive at all, but we also have the convention of not putting anything *too* sensitive into the work calendar.  You can be generic for things like vacations but for work related matters, being specific counts.
- Set up a convention with your boss when it comes to asynchronous communications.  Chat and email are not something that require you to respond immediately, and instead of assuming what their expectations are, it's better to re-set them together.

Now, if *none* of the above works out, or still results in friction points, then it'd be a good opportunity to look for a job and specify to your manager when you do leave that this was the reason - you offered a path forward on work visibility and you felt that their approach to it was not consistent with what was discussed or established.

Comment: thanks for the comment, he isn't really in the dark.. if it's the beginning, i'd be totally fine, but after 9 months of being here, i'm still being asked the same fundamental questions about things we discussed before.. that's what bothers me.

Comment: Good suggestions on some tangible things to do, appreciate that!

Comment: @olala: Well, doing this will at least give you some of your own CYA if you do decide to look elsewhere.  You still haven't really said how visible the work is, but if you do nothing else, at least spelling this out with your boss would be a useful exercise - either it leads to a change in how this question gets asked to you, or it leads to your amicable departure.

Comment: do you mean visible to him? Yes, he has access to the work I shared in a common folder. But what he needs is time to catch up with many emails/streams of work, that is beyond my control.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to want to sit down with him.  "Visible" means different things to different people.  If all someone sees are folders, that doesn't really indicate what purpose they serve or why they're there or what they really mean in terms of deliverables.  If you had a task board, that could present it in a better way.  I sure wouldn't be able to feel assuaged that you were working on something if all I saw was a mounted share with files in it, y'know

Comment: @olala Access Your manager having access to your work isn't the same as it being visible to them.
You _report_ to your manager. That means that you are responsible for providing them context about the work that you are doing, current progress, and anything impeding your progress.

Answer (score 15):

> Am I right that he is micromanaging?

Perhaps. Although much of what you wrote doesn't appear all that "micro". Perhaps it's just "different" than what you are used to. Or perhaps it's temporary until your new boss can learn to trust you.

I know I've worked for folks who expected rapid responses. And I have worked for folks who expected everyone to share their Calendar with them. (I think it was a huge mistake for you to refuse to do that.)

> What could I do to handle it?

Apparently, you need to learn to accept the fact that not all managers have the same expectations - particularly when they are new and don't yet know you.

If you haven't already done so, you should sit down for a chat with your manager. Learn his expectations for you. And meet those expectations to the best of your ability.

If you feel that the core issue is a lack of trust, you could ask "What can I do to earn your trust better?"

> Is it time to look for a new job...?

Perhaps. If you have already reached a conclusion that you cannot work with this new manager and his managerial style, you may need to find a new job.

Make sure while interviewing that you ask enough questions to determine if your future manager meets your expectations regarding micromanagement.

> Maybe it's more about his lack of experience and my frustration of our
> manager-report relationship where I have to constantly teach him
> things even after his break-in period.

You don't like your boss. It might be time to find a new job where you don't have to teach your manager.

Comment: Appreciate your comment, I still don't see why it's a huge mistake for me to refuse to share calendar details. I made some edit in my post and this isn't a norm to share calendar details in my profession. We can see if a person is busy or not but not where he/she is meeting with whom on what topic/details.

Comment: @olala Not to mention that in many/most cases, your manager will have access to this anyways, if (s)he really wants to get it. It just involves more paperwork on their end, and more headache that they would attribute to your refusal

Comment: @olala what right do you think you have to keep your calendar private? That's the details of the work you are being paid to do. Your boss supervises that work, and evaluates whether your employer should continue paying you to do it.

Comment: @olala at a minimum, it's imperative your manager is able to see your calendar so they know whether to send rescue workers into a dangerous situation to find you in an emergency situation.  (building on fire, tornado, etc.)  It's also your managers job to know what you're doing, would you rather have to explain what you did or have your manager able to look at your calendar without bothering you?

Comment: @fectin i don't think it's a right, if he insists, i probably will give it to him. The convention in our company and many others in the field i know is that nobody asks for this type of access. They can see if anyone is busy or not. We are in a matrix team environment and managers supervise on a high level and don't necessarily need to get into the details.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right that he is micromanaging?

Well, that may well be a matter of opinion.  Or maybe it's more clear-cut, but we would need more details about the job/industry to better understand the situation to make an informed assessment.  So I will give this a solid maybe.

> What could I do to handle it?

First of all, open your calendar and apologize for any prior misunderstanding.  If this is your personal calendar, that's one thing.  But if the calendar is business-related and is being stored on business computers, then it belongs to the business and so your manager has a right to it.  This is especially true if you're working a "full time" job where working during business hours is the typical expected norm.

Knowing the intended topics of meetings might help him formulate strategies involving multiple people, like having you help someone who is struggling or reducing duplication in different parts of the company.

Second, put forth extra effort to get on this person's good side.  That is always helpful in cases for negotiating, and since the person who is now your manager ended up getting this position which is designated to manage you, that person is likely the one negotating from a position of more strength.  (You probably don't want to be ticking that person off.)

Third, let the person know what you prefer.  The more valuable you seem, the more prone the manager may be to try extra hard to appease your wishes.

A few stories:

Multiple employers have adopted the slogan, "If there is time to lean, there is time to clean."  In other words, if you're not on break, be productive.  This might be more common in many customer-facing entry-level jobs.  Salespeople working on commission and independent contractors might commonly be managed with less precision.

I worked in a "call center" for years, and was almost always the employee getting the highest quality ratings on any team of 10-15 people that I'd be a part of.  I recall the second-highest-ranking person catching me in the hallway, and asking me why I am still in the position I am.  The reason was because my average call time was seventeen seconds too long.  This local leader acknowledged that sometimes the company may put too much emphasis on the "key performance indicators" metrics.  Not that his acknowledgement in the hallway ended up doing much of anything to help my position change.

I consider that to be rather micro-managed.  Although in the realm of trading stocks, I suppose that when split-seconds count, something over 15 seconds would be an enormously long time that could not be ignored.

I recall my father telling me about a meeting he had with his supervisor.  His boss called him by name, and then said, "You are the least supervised person in the entire company, with the least amount of oversight over what you are doing.  Even moreso than me."  After pondering that for a few seconds, he noted, "and I'm totally okay with this.  This does sound good to me."

My father was a salesperson who sometimes had seven or eight employers simultaneously, as he would sometimes sell product and so might work for 2 or 3 days a month for one company, and also help other companies.

So, to determine how much you are being overly-micromanaged or not may depend on quite a bit more context than what the question provided.  Ultimately, how "micro" a person is being managed may often be an opinion that is not shared equally between the perspectives of the employer and the managed employee.  Whether daily reporting is ridiculously pointlessly frequent or laughably lenient may vary between different scenarios.

> What could I do to handle it?

Seek to change reporting expectations.  Maybe that means a restructuring so that you aren't expected to report to this person.

But as long as the company does expect this of you...

Get on the person's good side, and make things work out as amicably as possible.

> Is it time to look for a new job...?

Yes.  Well, at least according to some people, it is always time to look for a new job.  You'll need to determine whether the supervisor's and/or company's level of cooperation with your requests/requirements are sufficient to make you happy enough to want to stay.

I recall one time when I wanted to re-define some of the work expectations.  I decided that if the conversation went poorly, the company might decide to not keep me.  So, I started looking into the possibility of having another job in my back pocket, just in case.  It turns out I found another job that I decided was more attractive anyway, so I did switch jobs, and never even bothered having the negotiations with the first company.

Obviously, individual experiences can be different.  "Your mileage may vary."  What you reported didn't indicate that the supervisor has been fed up enough to want to give you the axe, but we would need more context to answer that with more clarity.

(By the way, in my opinion, the way the question is asked now does seem to provide a useful key question in this "question" on Workplace.stackexchange.com, which is, "Am I right that he is micromanaging".  If you want more answers about another sub-topic, it may be most appropraite to simply create a new question with more focus on the specific other sub-topic.
Therefore, I'm actually not necessarily asking for more details to be added to this "question", even when I state that is why a more detailed answer couldn't be provided with how things were asked here.)

Answer (score 0):

They do the micromanagement if they have a fear. Very likely, this fear is directly or indirectly budget-related.

There is a reason that at least your last manager-switch was caused exactly by this.

You need to understand him, what is the cause of his fear, what is he wanting to reach in you. Either he only wants to understand, what and how are you doing, and he wants to see that you are doing as he expects. It has a smaller probability.

A higher probability is that he is actually wanting you to somehow change your work, because he believes that will be a step into a budget stabilization direction.

So, try to understand, what is he wanting from you.

I made my company calendar openly readable in the company. I.e. everybody can see, what am I doing and with whom. Of course I do not use it for private data. My goal with it is the increased openness, so they can understand me.

A new manager wants to understand a lot in his position, help him as you can! Not only because it is the best way to reach a good contact with him. *Another top reason is, if the managga understands you well, he will treat you better. Never miss the chance to share your point of view with a leader!*